# Having trouble with Phonegap (Android) and capturing click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to port an existing mobile web app to Phonegap, but I had difficulty handling a click event with jQuery (it worked in my browser, but not in the emulator). I've tried everything, but here is the general gist of what I'm trying to do.

HTML:

```
...
<span id="footerclick">Test</span>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='alert.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='phonegap.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/index.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   app.initialize();
</script>
```

alert.js:

```
$("#footerclick").click(function(){

    alert("I can't get this to show up");

});
```

That's pretty much it and I cannot get the alert to show up, I've tried wrapping it in $(document).ready(){} and a device listener. If I put something like onclick="alert('Hello')" as an attribute of #footerclick, that works also.

I think I just don't understand how Phonegap works with Javascript, but I've read the documentation several times and I don't get it. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Starting with the obvious... are you loading JQuery or forgetting to load it?
And by the time your code in alert.js executes, has JQuery loaded?

Comment: jQuery definitely has loaded (at the top of the page), at least when I run it in a browser. I am including it from CDNJS, so unless it is failing to load that then it should work.

Comment: But I mean, is it possible that alert.js is executing before JQuery's code because JQuery took longer to load?

Comment: @tomysshadow I added the following code and it says jQuery not found:

    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
      alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
    }else{
      alert("jQuery library is not found!");
    }

Even though I successfully accessed a click on the Phonegap's default HelloWorld page, so I'm very confused.

Comment: Okay, here's a question. If you take the source code of all these scripts, and instead of loading them externally, paste them on your page (just for the purpose of testing, not permanently) does JQuery load properly? My thoughts are that a callback is probably going to necessary if that is the case. If not, maybe JQuery is conflicting with another script on your page.

Comment: Thank you so much; it turns out that jQuery wasn't loaded -- something to do with not loading scripts from the web, and I included it locally and after some tweaking got the thing to finally register.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the problem thanks to @tomysshadow. It turns out that the emulator was blocking the loading of scripts from external domains (in particular, jQuery) and so the .click listener obviously didn't work. My temporary fix is to download and use a local version of jQuery, but I may update this answer when I figure out how to change the config file to allow these inclusions.